# Реализация Serialization API

Tags: java

Ребят нужна помощь, как реализовать сериализацию\десериализацию без использования serialization api, и соответственно ObjectOutputStream т.к он входит в этот механизм. Если поделитесь ссылкой на материал или дадите совет, буду очень благодарен

Comment: то есть, вы не хотите использовать `Serializable`

Comment: Да, все верно, как реализовать свой механизм сериализации? Как поместить данные объекта в массив байт, как различать объекты которые находятся в теле объекта а какие в коллекции в этом же объекте?

Comment: Нашел под кастомной сериализцией только как указать trancient поля, вся кастомность на этом заканчивается(

Comment: даже не знаю, вроде везде используется `ObjectOutputStream` - если вам нужно без него, то тут нужно писать свой велосипед. В каждом классе, который следует сериализовать/десериализовать определите свои методы для этих целей

Comment: я не нашел как решить проблему с разделителем, что закончился объект и начинается новый, и как тогда отследить когда очередь дойдет до динамического массива, ведь тогда все остальные объекты попадут в один массив.

Comment: поясните, почему вы не хотите использовать `Serializable` стандартные базовые установки?

Comment: т.к необходимо сделать свое, таково задание...Мне нужно понять в какую сторону копать, а не готовое решение)

Comment: А если записывать каждый объект в разные файлы? Мне кажется так вы решите проблемы с разделением

Comment: не подойдет, т.к в объекте есть разные поля, от обычное Object до Set<Object>, очень много файлов будет, нужно чтобы метод сериализии выдал готовый byte[]